# Inherit Square class into circle class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a square class, and i want to make a circle class that extends and inherits all of the square classes properties... How do i make a circle class do this.

Square class has draw, colour, falling and size properties. How do i get the circle class to inherit these things from the square class

Square Class

```
package GamePackage;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.Random;

public class Square {

    public int XLocation;
    public int Size;
    public int YLocation = -Size;
    public int fallSpeed = 1;
    Random rand = new Random();


   int R = rand.nextInt((256-40)+1)+40;
   int G = rand.nextInt((256-40)+1)+40; 
   int B= rand.nextInt((256-40)+1)+40;
   Color RandomColour = new Color (R, G, B);

    public int generateRandomXLocation(){
        return XLocation = rand.nextInt(Game.WINDOW_WIDTH - Size);
    }

    /*
    //creates a random value and stores it in squareWidth
    */
    public int generateRandomSquareSize(){ 
        return Size = rand.nextInt((30-17)+1)+17;
    }



    public int generateRandomFallSpeed(){
        return fallSpeed = rand.ints(3, 3, 8).findFirst().getAsInt();  // 3, 3, 8
    }

    /*
    //paints the square with the variables generated in the random methods
    */
    public void paint(Graphics g){

        g.setColor(RandomColour); 
        g.fillRect(XLocation,YLocation,Size,Size);
    }



    /*
    //sets the squareWidth and square fallSpeed to a random value for every square created
    */
    public Square(){
        generateRandomXLocation();
        generateRandomSquareSize();
        generateRandomFallSpeed();

    }



    public void update(){

        //changes the squares xLocation and fallSpeed if the created square reaches the bottom of the screen
        if(YLocation >= Game.WINDOW_HEIGHT){
            generateRandomXLocation();
            generateRandomFallSpeed();
            generateRandomSquareSize();
            YLocation = -Size;
        }

        //moves the square down if the square is inside the window
        if(YLocation <= Game.WINDOW_HEIGHT){
            YLocation += fallSpeed;
        }
    }


    public Rectangle GetBounds(){ 
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(XLocation,YLocation,Size,Size); 
       return rectangle;
    } 
}
```

Comment: For your information: __Inheriting circle from square doesn't sounds good__. Try create a __Shape__ class instead. Then inherit both Square and Circle from it.

Comment: For the sake of the game, they are both falling objects and it makes sense

Comment: Exactly. _"They both are falling objects"_ or _Shapes_ rather. Not Squares. Circles can't be squares !

Comment: Or even better, use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: How do you [fit a circle in a square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_peg_in_a_round_hole)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a subclass, just do class `A` extends `B`, where `B` is the super class. However if I were you, I will do something like:

```
public abstract class Shape{
    protected int locX;
    protected int locY;
}

public class Square extends Shape{
    //properties of Square
}

public class Circle extends Shape{
    //properties of Circle
}
```

---

**Or even without any inheritance..**

```
public abstract class ShapeProperties{
    protected int locX;
    protected int locY;
    //and any other members
}

public class Square{
    ShapeProperties sp;
}

public class Circle{
    ShapeProperties sp;
}
```

**Or..**

```
public interface Positionable{
    public void getLocX();
    public void getLocY();
}

public class Circle implements Positionable{
    //properties of Circle

    @Override
    public int getLocX(){

    }    

    @Override
    public int getLocY(){

    }  

    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new Rectangle(getLocX(), getLocY(), size, size);
    }
}
```

If you plan to extends Circle to Square for the reason of getting the bounds (or hitbox) of the circle objects. You could just write a `getBounds` method:

```
public class Circle{
    //properties of Circle

    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new Rectangle(locX, locY, size, size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is the wrong approach.

If you want to have the same properties for Square and Circle you should create an interface called Shape that has the properties you want implemented, you would then simply do `public class Square implements Shape` and `public class Circle implements Shape` and then implement the properties in both Square and Circle.

If you want only one implementation across all of your shapes then on top of creating the interface mentioned above you would also create an abstract class ShapeBase, your classes would then look like `public class Square extends ShapeBase implements Shape` and `public class Circle extends ShapeBase implements Shape` where your generic implementation would be done in the ShapeBase class and any specific implementation would be done in both Square and Circle.

Answer (score -1):

You should check some Java Tutorials. First Google Result gave me: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Are you thinking of this?

```
public class Circle extends Square {
}
```

Then, every public/protected (and perhaps package) method and attribute of `Square` is available in `Circle` as well.